# double value is changing when passed as argument to a function

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass double declared as a const to a function.

```
const double temp = 0.0007;
compute(temp); // calling compute function with double as argument
```

compute function is declared as compute(const double&)

```
    When i test it the double value gets converted to **0.00069999999999999999** 

compute (this=0x8173870, max_warpage_limit=@0xdaf450: 0.00069999999999999999,  at test.cpp:283
```

Precision is very crucial for me because I am using this value in calculations and this deviation is not acceptable.
Can experts here please share their opinion on what's happening?
Looking forward to your views

Comment: *Precision is very crucial for me because I am using this value in calculations and this deviation is not acceptable* -- The constant 0.0007 cannot be represented exactly in binary.  So you're already lost on the very first line of your code.

Comment: If the reason why you need these values to be exact is to do financial/monetary calculations, don't use `double`.  Either use integers, or get a library that uses types that does "exact math".

Comment: *Can experts here please share their opinion on what's happening?* -- There are no opinions -- that's the way it is with binary floating point.  You can try [this link](https://floating-point-gui.de/).